# Converting excel numeric date format into proper date format in R only in specific rows

Tags: r, excel, date, dplyr

I have a dataset where one column (character type) has different type of results i.e. dates(in excel numeric format), strings, numbers. There is another column that defines the type of result it is. For example - a date in the results column would have Date in the type column. Unfortunately these dates are in the excel numeric format and I would like to only convert these values into proper date format in R only if that result has Date in the type column and "B" in the type2 column. I hope that makes sense. This is my code so far:

```
data1 <- importedfile %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(type == "DATE" & type2 == "B", excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(result)), result))
```

I'm using mutate and an ifelse statement so that if columns type and type2 are equaled to DATE and B, then the corresponding value in result should have it's excel numeric format converted to a proper date format in R. However I get the following error:

Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `result`.
x NAs introduced by coercion
i Input `result` is `ifelse(...)`.
2: In excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(result)) :
NAs introduced by coercion

Is there something wrong with my ifelse statement?
If you guys have any inputs or tips on how to get past this, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

R allows only one type of data per column...most likely this will end up as character.